# How to disable Cmd+Shift+A and Cmd+Shift+M from CLI in MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line

How to disable those shortcuts using some CLI command/tool:

- "Open man Page in Terminal" - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- "Search man Page Index in Terminal" - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Both are located in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** as shown in the picture:

[image: 'Services' shortcuts]

I've managed before to enable/disable some of the 'Mission Control' and 'Spotlight' shortcuts by editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist"` ([link](https://github.com/rynkowski/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-macos/macos/set_system_preferences#L444)), but it looks they are defined somewhere else.

Is there any other plist, db, config file, CLI tool or API to modify these?

Comment: For people doing this from the UI, these commands are in a "Text" submenu in Ventura.

Comment: So... quite embarrassing, but I started to update the question to match macOS Ventura layout, but only then realized that this is not an **answer**. I was googling for _any_ way to disable those shortcuts. I still posted the update, but maybe we should do some Q&A for the GUI way of disabling them, noting that the SEO points to this question for "macOS disable cmd shift a"?

Answer (score 10):

In Ventura, this is in a new location `System Settings / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts... / Services / text`

[image]:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you disable these keyboard shortcuts via the UI, you're effectively adding the following key-value pair to the `NSServicesStatus` dictionary in the `pbs` domain:

```
"com.apple.Terminal - Search man Page Index in Terminal - searchManPages" = {
  "enabled_context_menu" = 0;
  "enabled_services_menu" = 0;
  "presentation_modes" = {
    ContextMenu = 0;
    ServicesMenu = 0;
  };
};
```

To do this via the CLI, you can `write` it in XML-encoded form using `-dict-add`:

```sh
VALUE='<dict><key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/><key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/><key>presentation_modes</key><dict><key>ContextMenu</key><false/><key>ServicesMenu</key><false/></dict></dict>'

defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus \
  -dict-add \
  'com.apple.Terminal - Open man Page in Terminal - openManPage' \
  "$VALUE"
defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus \
  -dict-add \
  'com.apple.Terminal - Search man Page Index in Terminal - searchManPages' \
  "$VALUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a (documented) command to delete a dictionary key item, but you can replace an existing dictionary key:

```
defaults write <whatever_the_file_is> -dict-add "Insert Bookmark" -string "@^b"
```

where @ is for the Command key, ^ is CTRL, $ is for shift, and ~ is for Alt.

So you'll need to provide another key sequence that you're not going to use. Obviously, you'll need to work out what the file is.

Comment: Yes, those keys don't trigger those Services in Terminal. They trigger those Services when I'm using IntelliJ Idea. I don't want to trigger them at all. I want to is to disable them using some CLI command.

Comment: If you never want them on, does it have to be a CLI command?

Comment: @benwiggly those two are default setting. I want to disable those shortcuts as part of my macos setup scripts. Over the past years, I disabled them manually several times and at this point I want to automate it. For other shortcuts I managed to do it, for these I can't find the way.